# Three.js canvas : Unload/load texture next panorama image

Tags: javascript, three.js

what is the best practice for display next panorama ? (change images) 
like this ?

Event click button ->

```
var materials = [

                loadTexture( 'PANO_NEXT0001.jpg' ), // right
                loadTexture( 'PANO_NEXT0003.jpg' ), // left
                loadTexture( 'PANO_NEXT0004.jpg' ), // top
                loadTexture( 'PANO_NEXT0005.jpg' ), // bottom
                loadTexture( 'PANO_NEXT0000.jpg' ), // back
                loadTexture( 'PANO_NEXT0002.jpg' )  // front

            ];
scene.remove(scene.children[0]);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 300, 300, 300, 7, 7, 7 ), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
mesh.scale.x = - 1;
scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,t think it would be change box geometry's material.Like :

```
var z=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('...jpg',THREE.UVMaping,function(){
            mesh.material.materials[i]=z;
        })
```

The `i` is the index of 6 materials.Have a loop for 6 faces's material.